# using groupby and order by with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use inner both GROUP BY and ORDER BY command in a same query with INNER JOIN, its is not happening.

i have Employee table:

```
+------------+------+
| id | fname | lname|         |
+------------+------+
| 11 | ABCD  | XHME |
| 12 | CDEF  | LMOP |
| 13 | MNOP  | DDDD |
+---------+---------+
```

emp_details table

```
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
| id | emp_id | company   | joining_date | Leaving_date | salary|
+---------+---------+--------------------+--------------|-------+
| 1 |   11    | Company 1 | 1999-01-03   | 2001-07-08   | 12000 |
| 2 |   11    | Company 2 | 2005-07-09   | 2007-01-31   | 16000 |
| 3 |   11    | Company 3 | 2002-04-07   | 2015-04-28   | 23000 |
| 4 |   12    | Companyxyz| 2000-10-12   | 2004-03-09   | 17000 |
| 5 |   12    | TestCom   | 2010-10-10   | 2014-10-10   | 35000 | 
+---+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

I want to display like this

```
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| User Name  | Last Company | Last Drawn Salary|
+------------+--------------+------------------+
| ABCD XMHE  | Company 3    |     23000        |
| LDEF LMOP  | TestCom      |     35000        |
+------------+--------------+------------------+
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT employee.id AS eid, employee.employer_id, employee.fname, employee.lname, emp_details.id as emid, emp_details.emp_id, emp_details.company, emp_details.joining_date, emp_details.leaving_date, emp_details.last_drawn_salary 
FROM employee
INNER JOIN emp_details ON employee.id = emp_details.emp_id 
WHERE employee.pan='".$pan."' 
GROUP BY emp_details.emp_id 
ORDER BY emp_details.id DESC
```

I also tried using like this `max(emp_details.id) as emid` but is still shows the 1st inserted column only. whats the problem here?

Comment: You want to display 3 columns, but select much more, why?

Comment: You don't need any aggregation to perform your query. Group by has no role to play. You need to get the basics straight.

Comment: what is employee.pan ?  and the value of $pan?

Comment: Here i have just mentioned the pattern, i want to display all the fileds which are in the select query @ gofr

Comment: if i dont use the Group by, then it will repeat the user name all the 3 times as there r 3 rcords in emp_details table. I wanna use only latest company info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final answer

   select CONCAT_WS(' ', e.fname, e.lnam) AS `User Name`,ed.company as last_company,esd.salary as max_salery from (select max(Leaving_date) as Leaving_date,emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id) eld INNER JOIN emp_details ed on ed.Leaving_date=eld.Leaving_date and ed.emp_id=eld.emp_id INNER JOIN (select max(salary) as salary,emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id) esd on ed.emp_id=esd.emp_id inner join Employee e on e.id = ed.emp_id;
    +-----------+--------------+------------+
    | User Name | last_company | max_salery |
    +-----------+--------------+------------+
    | ABCD XHME | Company 3    |      23000 |
    | CDEF LMOP | TestCom      |      35000 |
    +-----------+--------------+------------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


Step By Step Answer 


select max(Leaving_date),emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id;
+-------------------+--------+
| max(Leaving_date) | emp_id |
+-------------------+--------+
| 2015-04-28        |     11 |
| 2014-10-10        |     12 |
+-------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select max(salary),emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id;
+-------------+--------+
| max(salary) | emp_id |
+-------------+--------+
|       23000 |     11 |
|       35000 |     12 |
+-------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from (select max(Leaving_date) as Leaving_date,emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id) eld INNER JOIN emp_details ed on ed.Leaving_date=eld.Leaving_date and ed.emp_id=eld.emp_id;
+--------------+--------+------+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Leaving_date | emp_id | id   | emp_id | company    | joining_date | Leaving_date | salary |
+--------------+--------+------+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| 2015-04-28   |     11 |    3 |     11 | Company 3  | 2002-04-07   | 2015-04-28   |  23000 |
| 2014-10-10   |     12 |    5 |     12 | TestCom    | 2010-10-10   | 2014-10-10   |  35000 |
+--------------+--------+------+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select ed.emp_id,ed.company as last_company,esd.salary as max_salery from (select max(Leaving_date) as Leaving_date,emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id) eld INNER JOIN emp_details ed on ed.Leaving_date=eld.Leaving_date and ed.emp_id=eld.emp_id INNER JOIN (select max(salary) as salary,emp_id from emp_details group by emp_id) esd on ed.emp_id=esd.emp_id;
+--------+--------------+------------+
| emp_id | last_company | max_salery |
+--------+--------------+------------+
|     11 | Company 3    |      23000 |
|     12 | TestCom      |      35000 |
+--------+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @meenal Please check this answer

Comment: @ Mahesh Madushanka: Thank you very much! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

For the result you showed you can use a subquery with group by emp_details  emp_id

```
    SELECT 
      employee.id AS eid
    , employee.employer_id
    , employee.fname
    , employee.lname
    , emp_details.id as emid
    , emp_details.emp_id
    , emp_details.company
    , emp_details.joining_date
    , emp_details.leaving_date
    , emp_details.last_drawn_salary 
    FROM employee
    INNER JOIN emp_details ON employee.id = emp_details.emp_id
    WHERE (emp_details, emp_id)  in  ( select  max(emp_detail), emp_id  FROM   emp_details group by emp_id)
    ORDER BY emp_details.id DESC
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from   emp_details group by emp_id)
ORDER BY emp_details.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 14 `

Comment: This is not the query i provided  my don't have limit .. so please update you question adding the real query you are using .. so i cna evaluate it

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from   emp_details group by emp_id)
ORDER BY emp_details.id DESC`

Comment: Sorry.. Same error
`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from   emp_details group by emp_id)
ORDER BY emp_details.id DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You could flip this on it's head and look up in the emp_details table first to allow you to use DISTINCT, then join the employee, like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', employee.fname, employee.lname) AS `User Name`,
emp_details.company AS `Last Company`,
emp_details.salary,
DISTINCT(emp_details.emp_id)
FROM emp_details
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = emp_details.emp_id
## Add your WHERE statement here if you need it
ORDER BY emp_details.Leaving_date DESC
```

The CONCAT_WS allows you to join multiple columns. [See the documentation for CONCAT_WS for more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)

Let me know if that works, I've not had chance to test it.

Comment: Same result, i mean 1st inserted value i am getting :(

Comment: I've tried it from a different angle, see if that helps, have updated my answer